# python pygame int object error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[solved]

Pythons throwing me an a type error when I try to run my pygame script and I cant find any solutions..
I have looked around for solutions on other posts but couldn't find any that helped. Where am I going wrong??
The error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygameclass.py", line 43, in <module>
    ball.append(Ball(25, 400, 300 (50,50,50), "L", 25, 1, 100))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

My code;

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

w = 800
h = 400

z = 0 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))

pygame.display.update()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, radius, y,x , color, size, maxforce, force, life):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.size =size
        self.maxforce = maxforce
        self.force = force
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.life = life
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

    def fall (self):
        if self.y < h-self.radius:
            self.y +=self.force 
            if self.force < self.maxforce: 
                self.force+=1 
            elif self.y > h-self.radius or self.y == h-self.raidus: 
                self.y = h-self.radius -1 
                self.force = self.force*-1 
                self.maxforce = self.maxforce/2 
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius) 
            self.life-=1 
            if self.life<0: 
                ball.remove(self)



clock=pygame.time.Clock()
ball = []
ball.append(Ball(25, 400, 300 (50,50,50), "L", 25, 1, 100))

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for i in ball:
        i.fall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missed a comma before the tuple:

```
ball.append(Ball(25, 400, 300 <- missing a comma -> (50,50,50), "L", 25, 1, 100))
```

`ball.append(Ball(25, 400, 300,(50,50,50), "L", 25, 1, 100))`

You are also missing parens to call the fall method in your loop:

```
for i in ball:
    i.fall <- should be i.fall()
```

And a spelling mistake here:

```
elif self.y > h-self.radius or self.y == h-self.raidus  <- should be self.radius
```

Comment: have you considered doing this for a living? you've just saved myself alot of frustration, although despite these fixes, the ball doesnt seem to dry I'm just left with a black screen..

Comment: not sure why that is but you have another problem `ball.remove(self)` in that fall method, there is no ball

Comment: that could be the issue as to why im left with a blank screen, Sorry for the mess you've sifted through it's my first day learning to use pygame

Comment: no worries, I have not done a whole pile of pygame stuff but I imagine it will get easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot a comma.

```
ball.append(Ball(25, 400, 300, (50,50,50), "L", 25, 1, 100))
```

It thinks you're trying to call the function 300(), which is not possible.